# Definition of bold scalable delimiters using bm

Tags: delimiters, bm

I tried to define commands for scalable boldface delimiters via the `bmdefine` command from the `bm` package (obviously most of the packages involved seem unnecessary, but I need those packages, and perhaps the problem has to do with them):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools} % amsmath improvement
\mathtoolsset{mathic} % math italics correction
\usepackage[ scale = 1.09 ]{Baskervaldx} % text font
\usepackage{inconsolata} % sans serif monospaced ("typewriter") font
\usepackage{eulerpx} % math font
\usepackage{eucal} % upright cursive

% improved bold math
\newcommand\bmmax{0}
\usepackage{bm}

\bmdefine{\blparen}{\delimiter\delcode`(}
\bmdefine{\brparen}{\delimiter\delcode`)}
\bmdefine{\blbrack}{\delimiter\delcode`[}
\bmdefine{\brbrack}{\delimiter\delcode`]}

\begin{document}

\[       ) \quad       \bm{ ) } \quad       \brparen \]
\[ \Biggl( \quad \bm{ \Biggl( } \quad \Biggl\blparen \]
\[  \Bigr] \quad  \bm{ \Bigr] } \quad  \Bigr\brbrack \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the bold versions created with the `bmdefine` command are not working, but the "pure" command `\bm{***}` is working, even on the scaled versions of the delimiters (such bold variants are provided by the `eulerpx` package, I suppose). The commands created with `bmdefine` were taken from an answer from David Carlisle to a previous question I asked (now deleted).

My question is: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\newcommand\bmmax{0}` completely disabless `bm` it will certainly never do anything useful with that setting

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, I am really sorry for bothering you. In this example the issue is indeed solved by omitting that line of code, but I need it because in the original .tex file I am working I have a TON of definitions with `\bmdefine`, and omitting that instruction gets the LaTeX error "Too many math alphabets used in version bold."

Comment: it does not matter how many bmdefine you have, what matters is how many math fonts you load

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I get it, thank you for your explanation. I will try to reduce the number of math fonts I am using.

Comment: sure you may get that error but setting that to 0 avoids bm using too many math fonts by using no fonts at all it will not make anything bold other than "poor mans bold" over-printing 3 copies which is not usable for publication or `\boldsymbol` which switches to `\boldmath` locally and isn't used for scalable characters.  (correction for earlier comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example uses

```
\newcommand\bmmax{0}
```

so `bm` will not define any bold fonts so scalable characters are not bold.

some characters  will be made bold by the slower system used by `\boldsymbol` which locally switches to `\boldmath` but that is not usable by scalable chaaracters.

The setting disables 90% of the features of the package. Basically it is asking the package to make things bold while using no extra fonts.